# Keyboard not showing properly when text field is placed in sliver

Tags: dart, flutter, searchbar, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to create searchbar using Cupertino widgets and slivers.
Currently I have following structure:

```
CupertinoApp
  CupertinoTabScaffold
    CupertinoPageScaffold
      CustomScrollView
        SliverNavigationBar
        SliverPersistentHeader
          _SliverSearchBarDelegate
            CupertinoTextField
```

SliverPersistentHeader has delegate, which is implemented in the following way:

```dart
class _SliverSearchBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverSearchBarDelegate({
    @required this.child,
    this.minHeight = 56.0,
    this.maxHeight = 56.0,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => maxHeight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverSearchBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
```

And the screen widget looks like this:

```dart
class CategoriesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          CupertinoSliverNavigationBar( /* ... */ ),
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: _SliverSearchBarDelegate(
              child: Container(
                /* ... */
                child: CupertinoTextField( /* ... */ ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I focus in text field, it looks like keyboard is trying to show but then immediately hides. I was thinking that this behavior appears because of scrollview events, but adding ScrollController to CustomScrollView doesn't gave me any results (there was no scroll events while focusing text field).

I was also thinking that the problem appears only in simulator but on real device the behavior is same.

Here's the video demonstration of problem:

[image: video demonstration]

**UPDATE**: Thanks to [Raja Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9920254/raja-jain) I figured out that the problem is not in slivers or `CategoriesScreen` widget itself but in `CupertinoTabScaffold` in which this widget is wrapped. If I remove `CupertinoTabScaffold` and set `CupertinoApp`'s home widget to `CategoriesScreen` widget directly, the problem goes away. Here's my `main.dart` here, hope it will help, butI don't know how because there's nothing special in it:

```dart
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      /* ... */
      // home: CategoriesScreen(),
      home: CupertinoTabScaffold(
        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          /* ... */
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.all, size: 20.0),
              title: Text('Items'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.categories, size: 20.0),
              title: Text('Categories'),
            )
          ],
        ),
        tabBuilder: (BuildContext tabBuilderContext, int index) {
          return CategoriesScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I copied your code and tried to run.Code is running fine with expected behaviour,Maybe you are rebuilding your widget somewhere while clicking on text field. I'm attaching the code which i tried and working fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text("Demo"),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _SliverSearchBarDelegate(
                child: Container(
                  height: 20.0,
                  width: 20.0,
                  child: CupertinoTextField(/* ... */),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverSearchBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverSearchBarDelegate({
    @required this.child,
    this.minHeight = 56.0,
    this.maxHeight = 56.0,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => maxHeight;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverSearchBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've just copied your code, it works fine. I think I've found problem: my CategoriesScreen is used in CupertinoTabScaffold, inside tabBuilder. When I remove CupertinoTabScaffold and set CupertinoApp's home widget directly to CategoriesScreen, everything works fine. The problem still exists because I need to use CupertinoTabScaffold. Updated question

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and what solved my issue was to use CupertinoTabView in the CupertinoTabScaffold's tabBuilder, like this:

```
tabBuilder: (BuildContext tabBuilderContext, int index) {
      return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (context) => CategoriesScreen(),
      );
    },
```